# setting style sheets to html tags

Tags: c#, .net, itext

I have been trying out the following code on c# using itextsharp

```
Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER, 10, 10, 42, 35); 
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/Test.pdf"), FileMode.Create));

    doc.Open();

    HTMLWorker html = new HTMLWorker(doc);
    StyleSheet css = new StyleSheet();

    css.LoadTagStyle("div", "color", "red");
    html.Parse(new StringReader("<div>Sample text</div>"));
    css.LoadTagStyle("div", "color", "red"); 
    html.SetStyleSheet(css);
    doc.Close();
```

The test is however displayed in simple plain black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first answer is the `String` should be in HTML format.
And the second answer is `HTMLWorker` does not support `CSS` in this way.

You can use `XMLWorker` to achieve your goal.

```
    public static void pdfWithCSS()
    {
        Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER, 10, 10, 42, 35);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/TestWithCSS.pdf"), FileMode.Create));
        HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);

        htmlContext.SetTagFactory(Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory());

        //create a cssresolver to apply css
        ICSSResolver cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCssResolver(false);

        cssResolver.AddCss("div{color: red;}", true);
        cssResolver.AddCss("h1{color: green;}", true);

        //Create and attach pipline, without pipline parser will not work on css
        IPipeline pipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, new PdfWriterPipeline(doc, writer)));

        //Create XMLWorker and attach a parser to it
        XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(pipeline, true);
        XMLParser xmlParser = new XMLParser(worker);

        //All is well open documnet and start writing.
        doc.Open();
        string htmltext = "<html><body><h1>Heading in Green</h1><div>This is a div content. It should look red.</div></body></html>";
        xmlParser.Parse(new StringReader(htmltext));

        //Done! close the documnet
        doc.Close();
    }
```

But even if you want to use `HTMLWorker` then you have to provide your `CSS` attribute in the element itself with `style`.

See the example bellow:

```
    public static void pdfInLineCSS()
    {
        Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER, 10, 10, 42, 35);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/Test.pdf"), FileMode.Create));

        doc.Open();

        HTMLWorker html = new HTMLWorker(doc);
        /*StyleSheet css = new StyleSheet();*/ //Not supported
        /*css.LoadTagStyle("div", "color", "red");*/
        //css.LoadStyle("div", "color", "green");
        string simple = "<html><body><h1 style='color: green;'>Heading in Green</h1><div style='color: red;'>Sample text in red color.</div></body></html>";
        html.Parse(new StringReader(simple));
        //css.LoadTagStyle("DIV", "color", "red");
        /*html.SetStyleSheet(css);*/
        doc.Close();

    }
```

Resouces:

  [xmlworker-5.4.5](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/files/xmlworker/xmlworker-5.4.5/)

  [iTextSharp, a .NET PDF library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/)

  [xmlworker demo](http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/flatsite.html)

  And many more can not list all but a BIG THANKS to ALL

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Both codes work great. thanks a lot. I will be using the second one since i need a lot of css.
just out of curiosity though how is css.LoadTagStyle used? because i was trying for hours and could not figure it out.

Comment: do you have any idea what versions of html and css is this compatible with?

Comment: Neville, It does not support all tags and/or all selectors. Here is the list of [CSS Support](http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/CSS-conformance-list.htm)

Comment: @Iqbal link is not longer available.